# Resizing paper.js canvas programmatically: not properly redrawing part of canvas beyond original size

Tags: paperjs

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gnxdkqgh/5/

1. Try clicking on `x0.5` - everything works as expected
2. Try clicking on `x2` - part of the canvas that is beyond original rectangle is not redrawing properly
3. Try clicking on `x2` in rapid succession - you can see it draws animated dashed line, but fails to "clear" the canvas. It just draws over existing dashes, resulting in solid line.

Is it a bug in [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using latest Chrome. Here's a screenshot if you can't reproduce a problem:

[image: paper.js canvas resizing bug]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the size of the canvas without letting paper know that is what you've done. Rather than setting canvas size in your resize function, set paper.view.viewSize which will also reset the canvas size.

In the resize function replace

`canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;`

with

`paper.view.viewSize.width = w;
paper.view.viewSize.height = h;`

This will cause paper to change both the view size and the underlying canvas size - see [paperjs.org viewSize doc](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#viewsize)

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I tried doing `paper.viewSize = new paper.Size(w, h);` before instead of `paper.view.viewSize = new paper.Size(w, h);`.